# Why isn't $H_i(\mathbb{Z}^d,\mathbb{Z})=0$ for all $i\geq 2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

Since $\mathbb{Z}^d$ is a free group, shouldn't $H_i(\mathbb{Z}^2,\mathbb{Z})=0$ for every $i\geq 2$? Why isn't these two facts contraditory?

http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Group_cohomology_of_free_groups

http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Group_cohomology_of_free_abelian_groups

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a terminology issue, and admittedly, the terminology is a bit confusing to digest the first time around. $\Bbb Z^d$ is a free *abelian* group, but not a free group for general $d$. That is, it is a [free object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_object) in the category of abelian groups, but not a free object in the category of all groups. You might want to review the definition of a [free group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group). In particular, note that the free group $F_S$ on a set $S$ is never abelian when $\#S > 1$ (in which case $F_S\cong\Bbb Z$, so the only free abelian group which is a free group is $\Bbb Z$).

It might help to think of these phrases as having parenthesis: "free abelian group" means a "free (abelian group)," as opposed to a group which is both free *and* abelian (the only such group is $\Bbb Z$, we might call it an "abelian (free group)"). The words here are not associative and not commutative! :P

Comment: Here's a topological complement to Stahl's nice answer. Recall that $H_i(G,\mathbb{Z})=H_i(K(G,1),\mathbb{Z})$ where $K(G,1)=BG$ is the classifying space/Eilgenberg-Maclane space for $G$. Then, the issue is that $K(\mathbb{Z}^d,1)=(S^1)^d$ but $K(F_d,1)=S^1\vee\cdots\vee S^1$. This is intuitive algebraically since in the free abelian group the generators of $\mathbb{Z}^d$ 'dont' see one another' just like the factors $S^1$ don't see each other in $(S^1)^d$. But, in $F_d$ the generators 'see one another' in the sense that they don't commute, this being reflected by the fact that

Comment: the $S^1$'s in $S^1\vee\cdots\vee S^1$ do interact (by their intersection points).